# Autocad Diesel IF expression for sheet number tag

Tags: autocad

I am trying to automate a sheet tag with a Diesel expression in AutoCad.

This gets me the twelfth character in the drawing name. But as soon as I get to sheet 10 this will say its sheet 0.

`$(substr,$(getvar,dwgname),12,1)`

Does anyone know a way to get an If statement to see if the eleventh character is a 0 then run the above code else run `$(substr,$(getvar,dwgname),11,2)`

This is something i have tried.
`$(IF,substr,$(getvar,dwgname),11,1)="0"$(substr,$(getvar,dwgname),11,2,substr,$(getvar,dwgname),12,1)`

This appears to be similar to excel formulas. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Diesel expression i got working for auto sheet no. in autocad fields.

`$(if,$(substr,$(getvar,dwgname),11,1)"0",$(substr,$(getvar,dwgname),11,2),$(substr,$(getvar,dwgname),12,1))`

`$(if,$(substr,$(getvar,dwgname),11,1)"0"` = Does character 11 = 0
`,$(substr,$(getvar,dwgname),11,2)` = if no then take character 11 and the next char.
`,$(substr,$(getvar,dwgname),12,1))` = if char 11 is = to 0 then take only char 11.

I use two fields in my autocad border. One for the filename without the sheet no and this one for only the sheet number.

*Example filename: A150225_S001.dwg*

`$(substr,$(getvar,dwgname),1, 7)` = Use char from position 1 to 7. "`A150225`"

`$(if,$(substr,$(getvar,dwgname),11,1)"0",$(substr,$(getvar,dwgname),11,2),$(substr,$(getvar,dwgname),12,1))` = Use sheet no. at end of filename string. "`1`"

Hope this helps anyone looking to do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

The format for the Diesel if statement is:

```
$(if, expr, dotrue [, dofalse])
```

If the *expr* is nonzero, it evaluates and returns *dotrue*.

You seem to have a lot more going on in your sample.  Do the full evaluation (does the 11th character equal 0 in the *expr* portion and then set your returns, the false portion is optional and can be omitted.